# Mount point for Time Capsule Folder

Tags: macos, time-capsule

I have Time Capsule with folder(drive?) Data.  I didn't create this folder(drive?), it was already there when I have bought it.  I store books, music and films in this folder.

If I understand correctly when I reboot my Macbook and click on Time Capsule - Data on Finder, OSX mount this folder(drive?) to /Volumes folder.

Here is my /Volume:

```
# demas at MacBook-Air-demas.local in /Volumes [9:50:28]
$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxrwt@ 24 root   admin   816 Nov 16 09:49 .
drwxr-xr-x  35 root   wheel  1258 Nov 15 20:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root   admin   102 Sep  7 14:06 Data
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root   admin   102 Sep 23 05:51 Data-1
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root   admin   102 Oct  5 11:57 Data-10
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root   admin   102 Oct  5 16:28 Data-11
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root   admin   102 Oct 18 06:43 Data-12
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root   admin   102 Oct 18 11:40 Data-13
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root   admin   102 Oct 24 16:20 Data-14
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root   admin   102 Oct 25 06:45 Data-15
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root   admin   102 Oct 26 11:38 Data-16
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root   admin   102 Oct 27 04:31 Data-17
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root   admin   102 Oct 27 09:31 Data-18
```

As I see OSX create a new folder in /Volumes every time I want to mount the folder in my TimeCapsule.  How can I fix it?  How can I set one folder to mount Data folder(drive?) in my Time Capsule ?

**Update**

```
$ ls -la /Volumes/Data-7
total 40
drwx------   1 demas  staff    364 Nov 16 12:54 .
drwxrwxrwt@ 24 root   admin    816 Nov 17 07:37 ..
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 demas  staff  18436 Nov 16 13:09 .DS_Store
drwxrwxrwt@  1 demas  staff    264 Sep  2 21:24 .TemporaryItems
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 demas  staff      0 Aug 26 21:22 .com.apple.timemachine.supported
drwxrwxrwx@  1 demas  staff    296 Nov 17 07:37 MacBook Air - demas.sparsebundle
drwxrwxrwx   1 demas  staff   1112 Jul 26 15:52 books
......


$ ls -la /Volumes/Data-8
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root  admin  102 Oct  2 05:56 .
drwxrwxrwt@ 24 root  admin  816 Nov 17 07:37 ..
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root  admin  102 Oct  2 05:56 Backups.backupdb
```

Comment: Output of `ls -le` on `/Volumes/Data-18`?? Wondering if those entries actually contain anything..

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Hmm.. and with all those entries in `/Volumes` are they all mounted or is there just one "Data" mountpoint and the same showing from the TimeCapsule?

Comment: Only one mount point on the time. But if I reboot, OSX create a new folder in /Volumes every to mount the folder in my TimeCapsule.

Comment: If you have the Data folder in your Login Items, remove it and turn off Time Machine. Reboot and check `/Volumes` again.